# Create a svelte component with a function recive a data by post

Tags: post, components, call, svelte

I need to expose a .svelte component that receives data through the post method, so that an external service can consume it and that the received data can be displayed as received

// test.svelte

```
<script>

let name="";
let age="";
let gender ="";

export async function post({request}){
       const body = await request.json();
       console.log(body);
       name = body.name;
       age = body.age;
       gender = body.gender;
       return {
             body:JSON.stringify({body})
       } 
    });

</script>
<form>
    <div>
       <p>{name} {age} {gender}</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Check this picture maybe understand better](https://ibb.co/6rJ7qmM)

Comment: Where's the problem or what's the question?

Comment: Hello, I need to receive a json or data that arrives through a post method and that is inside a .svelte component

Comment: @SDCOfficeOlimpia Please re-elaborate your question to provide more details. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I need to expose a .svelte component that receives data through the post method, so that an external service can consume it and that the received data can be displayed as received...  please check this image ->  https://ibb.co/6rJ7qmM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.svelte files don't handle POST request directly.

The code you've written doesn't work inside the `<script>` tag of a Svelte component. Post data is not available in the frontend.

However if you're using a up-to-date SvelteKit and are hosting a non-static version.
(By using the @sveltejs/adapter-node for example)

You can use the [Shadow Endpoint](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3679) feature:

```html
<!-- src/routes/test.svelte -->
<script>
export let name;
</script>

<h1>{name}</h1>
```

```js
// src/routes/test.js
export async function post({ request }) {
  const data = await request.json();
  return {
    body: {
      name: data.name
    } 
  }
};
```

When you create an endpoint with the same filename, the post request is handled by the endpoint (backend) and if the request contains an `Accept: text/html` or `Accept: */*` header the server will respond with the SSR page using the values from the body as props.