# SvelteKit Load data from backend to component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a Java Spring API i want to get data from , and display them in my component eg. Test.svelte i use in my +layout.svelte . I dont want to have a fetch directly to the Api But the svelte application first .

User (Test.svelte) <-> SvelteApplication <-> API

What is the correct way to do this ?

I Have tried using the accepted approach here

[Create a svelte component with a function recive a data by post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230261/create-a-svelte-component-with-a-function-recive-a-data-by-post)

By creating a Test.js but it dosent seem to ever fetch data (Tried logging in console) and my variables stay as undefined .

Comment: I would not recommend this. Currently it looks like you would need a separate file in a separate folder for every API endpoint with a different path. You could of course define fewer endpoints and work primarily with query parameters or use something like the [hooks](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API has since changed, see the [docs on routing](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).

API methods are associated with the current route (directory-based) via a `+server.js/ts` file. E.g. if you have a `+page.svelte` and a `+server.js/ts` directly in `src/routes`, they both refer to the `/` route (unless a different base URL is set). For layouts you get a `layout.server.js/ts` file instead, they do not support anything other than the `load` function, though, as they are not bound to a specific route.

Using those two files you could send a request like this:

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script>
    async function onRequest() {
        const res = await fetch('/', { method: 'POST' });

        if (res.ok == false) {
            alert('Error');
            return;
        }
        
        const result = await res.json();
        alert('OK: ' + result.value);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={onRequest}>Request</button>
```

```js
// +server.js
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const POST = () => json({ value: 42 });
```